# Swagger UI Express with API Versioning

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, api-versioning

I am using swagger-ui-express and swagger-jsdoc for API Documentation of my node app. The point here is that I have two versions of API in my App and I want to document both of them. I have seen that in .NET Core there is an option available to define the specs and choose one from a dropdown in top bar. I am looking for a similar solution

[image]

As a dropdown can be seen in top bar I want similar via swagger-ui-express. Is it possible or if anybody has implemented the same for API Versioning?

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: None of those links answers the question. I am not talking about multiple hosts. Where is the answer in your link https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/408.

Kindly read the question carefully

Comment: Thanks for the efforts you have put in but that doesn't help. Below answer had served my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I propose is not specific to API versioning, but you can have a dropdown of URLs the end-user can choose from. According to the [docs](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express#load-swagger-from-url), you would need to pass a `swaggerOptions` object:

```
const swaggerOptions = {
  explorer: true,
  swaggerOptions: {
    urls: [
      {
        url: 'https://v1/swagger.json',
        name: 'v1'
      },
      {
        url: 'https://v2/swagger.json',
        name: 'v2'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```